# Not able to populate multiselect dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I am trying to dynamically populate the options of a multiselect dropdown.
Below is my code:

```
<label for="serviceTypeCntrl" style="padding-left: 14px;">Service Type : </label>
<select id="serviceTypeCntrl" name="serviceTypeCntrl" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

Then I am trying to populate the dropdown dynamically using ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {         
    $.ajax({            
        url : 'ServicerServlet?identifier=PopulateServiceType',
        type : 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(responseText) {
            alert(responseText);
            //var option="";
            $("#serviceTypeCntrl").find("option").remove();
            responseText.forEach(function(serviceType) {
            //option = $('<option>' + serviceType + '</option>');
            //$('#serviceTypeCntrl').append(option);
            //$('<option>').text(serviceType).appendTo('#serviceTypeCntrl');
            $('#serviceTypeCntrl').append($('<option>').text(serviceType)); 
            })
        }        
   });
});
```

Value is coming from the servlet but the dropdown is not getting populated.
What am I doing wrong here?
Looking forward to your answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the value of `responseText`?

Comment: the thing you're doing should work if `serviceType` actually contains the option text on each iteration...

Comment: Thanks for the reply billy. Yes on each iteration I am getting the value. but it is not getting set.

Comment: Azim here is my response text.["Service1", "Service2", "Service3", "Service4", "Service5", "Service6"]

Answer (score 1):

Try once like this

```
$('#serviceTypeCntrl').append("<option>" + serviceType + "</option>"));
```

instead of this

```
$('#serviceTypeCntrl').append($('<option>').text(serviceType));
```

Comment: Thanks jyothi for the reply. I tried the below code but strangely none of the code is working

Comment: response text.["Service1", "Service2", "Service3", "Service4", "Service5", "Service6"]

Comment: @Roy I saw your AJAX call. You given it as POST type. But nothing, (atleast empty `json` ) also not posting. How you are getting the response?

Comment: i am posting a query template.And then I am getting the response from MySQL, converting it to json string and then sending it to ui.

Comment: One finder though, the above piece of code works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't work. Means the above code populates the dropdown sometimes and sometimes it doesn't. That's strange...